# Declarative conditional validation of a field based on other one from parent model

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-validation, system.componentmodel

I have two separate types:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public Contact ContactDetails { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    [RequiredIfActive]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

What I need is to perform conditional declarative validation of internal model field, based on some state of the parent model field - in this particular example an `Email` has to be filled, if `IsActive` option is enabled.

I do not want to reorganize these models taxonomy, while in the same time I need to use attribute-based approach. It seems that from within an attribute there is no access to the validation context of the parent model. How to reach or inject it there?

```
public class RequiredIfActiveAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, 
                                                ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        /* validationContext.ObjectInstance gives access to the current 
           Contact type, but is there any way of accessing Person type? */
```

**Edit:**

I know how conditional validation can be implemented using Fluent Validation, but I'm NOT asking about that (I don't need support regarding Fluent Validation). I'd like to know however, if exists any way to access parent model from inside `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute`.

Comment: Fluent Validation is much better than default MVC validation. I switched to fluent validation 3 months ago, after using default mvc validation for 4 years.

Comment: @Softlion: This question is mainly my curiosity, I'm not trying to validate anything. I'm not trying to simplify my life in this particular context either. That's why Fluent Validation suggestions do not target my question at any level.

Answer (score 1):

**My Suggestion**

*Go to Tools => Library Package Manager => Package Manager Console and install Fluent Validation.*

[image]

**Action Methods**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new Person
    {
        Name = "PKKG",
        IsActive = true,
        ContactDetails = new Contact { Email = "PKKG@stackoverflow.com" }
    };
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Person p)
{
    return View(p);
}
```

**Fluent Validation Rules**

```
public class MyPersonModelValidator : AbstractValidator<Person>
{
    public MyPersonModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.ContactDetails.Email)
            .EmailAddress()
            .WithMessage("Please enter valid email address")
            .NotNull().When(i => i.IsActive)
            .WithMessage("Please enter email");
    }
}
```

**View Models**

```
[Validator(typeof(MyPersonModelValidator))]
public class Person
{
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "IsActive")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public Contact ContactDetails { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@{
    var actionURL = Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { area = "AreaName" },
                           Request.Url.Scheme);
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, 
                                                    new { @action = actionURL }))
    @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Name);
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Name);

    @Html.EditorFor(i => i.IsActive);
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.IsActive);

    @Html.EditorFor(i => i.ContactDetails.Email);
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.ContactDetails.Email);
    <button type="submit">
        OK</button>
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort but, as it has been clearly annotated in the question itself (and in the comments, which are now removed), Fluent Validation is not the solution I'm looking for in my particular case.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done via an attribute on `Contact.Email` since, as you have already discovered, the parent `Person` is not available from the attribute context at runtime.  To enable this scenario via a validation attribute, the attribute must decorate the `Person` class.  You have two choices for this with `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` attributes: [`CustomValidationAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute) or a custom `ValidationAttribute` subclass that targets `Person`.

Here's what the two classes might look like when using `CustomValidationAttribute`:

```
[CustomValidation(typeof(Person), "ValidateContactEmail")]
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public Contact ContactDetails { get; set; }

    public static ValidationResult ValidateContactEmail(Person person, ValidationContext context)
    {
        var result = ValidationResult.Success;
        if (person.IsActive)
        {
            if ((person.ContactDetails == null) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(person.ContactDetails.Email))
            {
                result = new ValidationResult("An e-mail address must be provided for an active person.", new string[] { "ContactDetails.Email" });
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you please take out some time to give a  code example for more details if possible?

Comment: I've added an example for CustomValidationAttribute.  Do you need one for a custom ValidationAttribute subclass as well?